# get detailed information about sources optained through desktopCapturer in electron desktop application

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, electron, desktopcapturer

I am creating an desktop application using electron for the Linux platform. I am able to get screenshot of the entire screen or the each screen. Following is the code to that captures screenshot and passes to another function that saves screenshot as png file :

```
    function getMainSource(desktopCapturer, screen, done) {
  let options = {
    types:  ['window', 'screen'],
    thumbnailSize: screen.workAreaSize
  };
  desktopCapturer
    .getSources(options)
    .then(sources => {
      for (const thisSource of sources) {
        console.log(`SOURCE NAME (${thisSource.id}) ::`, thisSource.name);
      }
      const isMainSource = s =>
        s.name === 'Entire Screen' ||
        s.name === 'Screen 1' ||
        s.name === 'Entire screen';
        console.log(`isMainSource => `,sources);
      done(sources.filter(isMainSource)[0]);
      //done(sources[3]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return console.log('cannot capture screen:', err);
    });
}
```

getSources function returns sources object that does not contain sufficient information about the application / window . It contains only 5 properties (name,id,thumbnail,display_id,appIcon) something like below :

```
{
    name: 'Landing Page- Project.docx - LibreOffice Writer',
    id: 'window:117440667:0',
    thumbnail: NativeImage {
     ....
     ...
    },
    display_id: '',
    appIcon: null
}
```

name is the title of the application which does not contain information about the app always.

Is there any way that I can  get more information (exact application name, URL in case of browser) about the each app with electron APIs or shell script or any other feasible way.

Thanks in advance